# Error Flag in vba is broken

Tags: vb.net

So, I have a problem and when i input incorrect input data or correct input data the message box displays the same every time regardless of the input. now, i know this has to do something with my error flag but i cant find the issue behind it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim area As Integer
    Dim Length As Decimal
    Dim Width As Decimal
    Dim Depth As Decimal
    Dim CostNo As Integer
    Dim CostNa As String
    Dim combo As String
    Dim ErrorFlag As String

    Private Sub Area2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Area2.Click
        Length = txtLength.Text
        Width = txtWidth.Text
        Depth = txtDepth.Text

        ErrorFlag = ErrorLook(Length, Width, Depth)
        If ErrorFlag = "True" Then
            MsgBox("Invalid")
        ElseIf ErrorFlag = "False" Then
            MsgBox("u Good")
        End If

        'getting input from the costumer number text box
        'CostNo = CostumerNo.Text
        'getting input from the costumer name text box
        'CostNa = CostumerName.Text
        'store the names together as a new variable
        'combo = CostNo & " " & CostNa

        'displays the full name in the third text box
        Result.Text = combo & " " & "Area " & a(Width, Length)
    End Sub
    'sets the boundaries for the input values
    Public Function ErrorLook(ByVal w As Decimal, ByVal l As Decimal, ByVal d As Decimal) As String
        Dim FlagError As String
        FlagError = "False"
        If txtLength.Text < 1 Or txtLength.Text > 10 Then ErrorFlag = "True"
        If txtWidth.Text < 1 Or txtWidth.Text > 10 Then ErrorFlag = "True"
        If txtDepth.Text < 1 Or txtDepth.Text > 2 Then ErrorFlag = "True"
        Return FlagError
    End Function
    'calculates the area
    Public Function a(ByVal w As Decimal, ByVal l As Decimal) As String
        Dim area2 As Decimal
        area2 = Width * Length
        Return area2
    End Function
    'calculates the width
    Public Function L(ByVal W As Decimal) As Decimal
        Width = txtWidth.Text + (2 * txtDepth.Text)
        Return Width
    End Function
    'calculates the length
    Public Function W(ByVal L As Decimal) As Decimal
        Length = txtLength.Text + (2 * txtDepth.Text)
        Return Length
    End Function
    'displays the date and time of the system it is eing run from
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        lbTime.Text = Now()
    End Sub

    'the clear button for clearing all of the fields
    Private Sub CA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CA.Click
        Reset()
        txtDepth.Text = ""
        txtLength.Text = ""
        txtWidth.Text = ""
        CostumerName.Text = ""
        CostumerNo.Text = ""
        Result.Text = ""
        output.Text = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: is this vb.net or vba?...

Comment: @CallumDA - judging from the  `As Decimal` I vote for vb.net.

Comment: its vba event driven for VB forms

Comment: vb.net sorry that was mistake

Comment: It is always a bad idea to do arithmetic with strings. Turn Option Strict on. It might highlight some of the difficulty. I think your flag should be a boolean but I don't think that is the problem. I would think you would want an Exit Sub after the Invalid message.

Comment: okay :) cheers buddy

Comment: it works now thank for the help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Function `ErrorLook` always returns the string `"False"` because the variable `FlagError` is returned but never set to `"True"`. Instead the variable `ErrorFlag` is being set. Moreover, you're using the arguments (w,l and d) nowhere.

(The same applies to all of your functions.)

You can change the Function like following and it should work.

```
Public Function ErrorLook() As String
    If txtLength.Text < 1 Or txtLength.Text > 10 Then Return "True"
    If txtWidth.Text < 1 Or txtWidth.Text > 10 Then Return "True"
    If txtDepth.Text < 1 Or txtDepth.Text > 2 Then Return "True"

    Return "False"
End Function
```

But,
you should use `Boolean` instead of string, like already mentioned in comments.

Furthermore, you need to check if the content of the Textbox is numeric.

The call and the function would then look like following:

```
Private Sub Area2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Area2.Click
    Decimal.TryParse(txtLength.Text, Length)
    Decimal.TryParse(txtWidth.Text, Width)
    Decimal.TryParse(txtDepth.Text, Depth)

    If ErrorLook(Length, Width, Depth) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid")
    ElseIf ErrorFlag = False Then
        MsgBox("u Good")
    End If
    ...
End Sub

Public Function ErrorLook(ByVal w As Decimal,
                          ByVal l As Decimal,
                          ByVal d As Decimal) As Boolean

    Return w < 1 OrElse
           w > 10 OrElse
           l < 1 OrElse
           l > 10 OrElse
           d < 1 OrElse
           d > 2
End Function
```